# Session data not holding up in Chrome since SameSite

Tags: php, session, samesite

Since the last Chrome 80 update, I've had to set cookies to `SameSite=>None` and `Secure`.  On the site I made the modifications, they are using PHP52.  I am passing data to another site, which directs them back, and their system then reads session data to close out the communication.

The problem I am having is that even though I am able to handle the cookies, when passed back, the user is being given a new `PHPSESSID` so the data they have held for the user is now missing.  Is this something anyone else has experienced?

I read into `session_set_cookie_params` but that doesn't seem to be relevant (unless I am reading it wrong) in case it is similar to the cookie issue.  I'm a bit lost as to where to look on this one as I didn't think `samesite` would affect session data.

Comment: I have (quite) the same problem, but with a 3D Secure redirect. On my site, i have a session cookie, i redirect to another site, and then when the user complete the payment, he had no session, so the payment fail. But the session cookie is not sended to the gateway.

Comment: I've tried adding `header('Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID='.session_id().'; Domain='.COOKIE_DOMAIN.'; Path='.COOKIE_DIR.'; SameSite=None; Secure', false);` but it makes a new SESSID with a leading . on the domain.